# Cannot get Controller to build model form query and parameter passed in - multiple models to get data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have 4 simpler models in the larger model I am using here and doing a complex query with a result set.  Works great.  I have a parameter that is passed in to complete the update in a new table comprised of all parts.

So, int(passed parameter) comes in as expected from action on last view
Data queries as expected from query in controller..

I have built other actions with a single model, no issue.

I have tried creating a new model and then specifically adding to the model and I get a null reference error on the int to the model value: (object null reference error)
code not currently there:

```
var model = new AddCompToEventClass();
model.Compeditor.CompeditorId = compeditorid;
```

I just cannot figure out how to get everything into the model to pass on to the next view.

controller code:  Has compeditorId commented.  The compeditorid parameter passes as expected to the controller.

```
    public ActionResult AddCompToEventClass (int compeditorid)
{
    // ?? model.Compeditor.CompeditorId = compeditorid;
    var model = from o in _db.Events
                join o2 in _db.Event_Classes on o.EventID equals o2.EventID
                where o.EventID.Equals(o2.EventID)
                join o3 in _db.Class_Definitions on o2.ClassID equals o3.Class_Definition_ID
                where o2.ClassID.Equals(o3.Class_Definition_ID)
                where o.CurrentEvent.Equals(true)
                select new AddCompToEventClass { Event = o, Event_Class = o2, Class_Definition = o3 };

return View(model);
```

Here is the model (based on 4 other models)

```
 namespace eManager.Web2.Models
{
    public class AddCompToEventClass
    {
        public Compeditor Compeditor { get; set; }
        public Event Event { get; set; }
        public Event_Class Event_Class { get; set; }
        public Class_Definition Class_Definition { get; set; }
    }
}
```

updated code: I now get the Competitor and the Query, but only the query is passed into the model... With the competitor in the query I get a Linq exception.

```
public ActionResult AddCompToEventClass (int compeditorid)
    {
        var Compeditor = new Compeditor();
        Compeditor.CompeditorId = compeditorid;

        var model = from o in _db.Events
                    join o2 in _db.Event_Classes on o.EventID equals o2.EventID
                    where o.EventID.Equals(o2.EventID)
                    join o3 in _db.Class_Definitions on o2.ClassID equals o3.Class_Definition_ID
                    where o2.ClassID.Equals(o3.Class_Definition_ID)
                    where o.CurrentEvent.Equals(true)
                    select new AddCompToEventClass { Event = o, Event_Class = o2, Class_Definition = o3 };



    return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Note:  My ultimate goal is to have t queries that build one model for return.  The second query using the compeditorid value to pull data from that view.  So, 2 queries to one model using the passed in paramter to define the compeditor.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a null reference error on the int to the model value: (object null reference error)

You are missing another constructor possibily:

```
var model = new AddCompToEventClass();

// model.Compeditor is most likely null

model.Compeditor = new Compeditor();

model.Compeditor.CompeditorId = compeditorid;
```

**update**

Updated Query:

```
public ActionResult AddCompToEventClass (int compeditorid)
{
  var model = from o in _db.Events
    join o2 in _db.Event_Classes on o.EventID equals o2.EventID
    where o.EventID.Equals(o2.EventID)
    join o3 in _db.Class_Definitions on o2.ClassID equals o3.Class_Definition_ID
    where o2.ClassID.Equals(o3.Class_Definition_ID)
    where o.CurrentEvent.Equals(true)
    select new AddCompToEventClass 
    {
      Event = o, 
      Event_Class = o2, 
      Class_Definition = o3,
    };

  model.Compeditor = new Compeditor
  {
    CompeditorId = compeditorid
  };

  return view(model);
}
```

Comment: Ah.. thanks!  That works.. but one other issue.  How do I reference the query into the model?  I think I can set it to "model = " but in the select the new AddCompToEventClass would have to go?.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question (sorry).  I will guess at what you are asking with and update to my answer.

Comment: My apologizes.  There are 2 var model established above.  There cannot be 2 I believe.  How to I change the second to be able to have the model be updated with out recreating it.

Comment: Your question is still not clear.  Do you want to use the same model for two controller actions?  Do you have 2 queries (which I do not see a 2nd query, I only see 1) that you want to populate 1 model?  My answer populates the mode ONCE with both the query and the passed in value.

Comment: It makes sense to me now.  I am much closer and but now getting a Linq exception:  The entity or complex type 'eManager.Web2.Infastructure.Compeditor' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: model.Compeditor = new Compeditor is still having issues.  "does not contain a definition for Compeditor"  Should I add a deffinition somewhere?  And thanks so much for your help at this point.